# Table is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, servlets, hql

I need help with my simple servlet in Java.
I have a Login form (email and password fields) in HTML file, a Java servlet and a utility for the login in witch is checked if into de database exists a couple with the same email and password.
Running the program I have a Syntax Error with my query, the error says that "User is not mapped".
I think that this is a dummy error, could anyone help me?

Here the model.User class

```java
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table( name = "USERS",
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email"})})

public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_id", nullable=false, unique=true)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="firstName", length=40, nullable=false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="lastname", length=40, nullable=false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email", length=40, nullable=false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name="password", length=40, nullable=false)
    private String password;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Here the utility.LoginDao class

```java
public static boolean validateCredentials(String email, String password){
        Session session = DbService.getSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        Query query = session.createQuery
                ("from Users u where u.email=:email and u.password=:password");

        query.setParameter("email", email);
        query.setParameter("password", password);

        List list=query.list();
                ...
```

Here my LoginServlet doPost() method:

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {  
        String email = request.getParameter("email");  
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if(LoginDao.validateCredentials(email, password)){
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("SigninSuccess.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);
        }
        else{  
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");  
            rd.include(request,response);  
        }  
    }
```

Here signin.html form file

```html
<form method="POST" action="LoginServlet">
            <p>
                <label for="fname">E-mail</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="e-mail">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="lname">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
            </p>        
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
            <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="./signup.html">Create an account</a></p>
        </form>
```

this is the error:

User is not mapped [from User u where u.email=:email and p.password=:password]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    ...

Comment: how is `jquery` related to the problem?

Comment: When I type email and password into a HTML form a LoginServlet is invoked.

Comment: `String email = request.getParameter("email");  
     String password = request.getParameter("password");
     
     if(LoginDao.validateCredentials(email, password)){
      RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("SigninSuccess.jsp");
   view.forward(request, response);
     }
     else{  
         out.print("Sorry username or password error");  
         RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");  
         rd.include(request,response);  
     }  `

Answer (score 2):

Here you are creating `Query` using the table name (users) in the database -

```
Query query = session.createQuery
                ("from Users u where u.email=:email and u.password=:password");
```

That's why you are getting the error. You need to use the entity name - `User` -

```
Query query = session.createQuery
                ("from User u where u.email=:email and u.password=:password");
```

HQL expect you are using java class name and java property name. You also have to care that you are using `javax.persistence.Entity` not `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity`

Comment: I have used - User - in my query but I have the same error

Comment: @AntonioArgentieri Can you also check your import statement which `Entity' you are importing? It need to be `javax.persistence.Entity`

Comment: Yes, it is the same import.

Comment: I have edit my question with the complete User class.

Comment: Are you also using capital U at `User` - it is case sensitive. And do you also done @componentScan?

Comment: I don't use @componentScan, in which way I have to use it? I have uploaded all code paths in my questions.

Answer (score 0):

[Razib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2986537/razib) gave you the correct answer in telling you to use `User` in your query rather than `Users`. If you are still getting the same error, then it can only be because Hibernate has not found the `@Entity` class.

Please run the following code and respond with the output.

```
sessionFactory.getConfiguration()
                .getClassMappings()
                .forEachRemaining(pc -> System.out.println(pc.getEntityName() + "\t" + pc.getTable().getName()));
```

hint:  To get the `sessionFactory`, just autowire it in a service or a dao:

```
@Autowired
private LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory;
```

Comment: I'm sorry i read thath "@Autowired" annotation is used with Spring but I use Hibernate and Postgresql

Comment: Postgres has nothing to do with this, but sure.

If you're not using Spring, you can simply use the hibernate configuration object directly.

My suggestion above becomes:

configuration
                .getClassMappings()
                .forEachRemaining(pc -> System.out.println(pc.getEntityName() + "\t" + pc.getTable().getName()));

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved my problem. I forgotten to add `config.addAnnotatedClass(model.User.class);` in my configuration in LoginDao class. Thanks all.